# Mechanize Problems Connecting to HTTP Proxy...Ruby

Tags: ruby, proxy, mechanize

I have a proxy set up and running completely fine on my local host.  I can connect to the proxy completely fine running this code.

```
Net::HTTP::Proxy('http://localhost', 1234).start  #do whatever I want after this point
```

I can connect to it through a browser completely fine, however when I go to run it on mechanize it completely fails.  Here's the code.

```
require 'mechanize'
agent=Mechanize.new
agent.set_proxy('localhost', 1234)
agent.get('http://google.com')   #or any website for that matter
```

Here's the error I get back

```
Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error: too many connection resets (due to end of file reached - EOFError) after 0 requests on 22249020, last used 1376802493.5352573 seconds ago
```

I've read that the versions after 1.0.0 have difficulties connecting to http proxies, but I need to and I'm currently running version 2.7.2.  Is there anything I can do to connect to a proxy.

Comment: You can get it resolved from here [**`Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error: too many connection resets (due to Connection reset by peer - Errno::ECONNRESET) after 2 requests on 14759220`**](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/issues/123)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already read that post and I did not find a solution that fixed m problem.  Anything else that may be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some proxies can't handle persistent connections (keep-alive). You need to make sure to use a HTTP/1.1-aware proxy.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ruby are you running? I have this issue with Ruby 2.1.5 and Mechanize, but not with Ruby 1.9.3.

Presumably you've resolved your problem, but for anyone else who might end up here, downgrading to Ruby 1.9.3 might be a workaround.